# How to download large size files with axios as stream and download as zip in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, file, local-storage

I am building a frontend application to download files from a remote object storage server like S3. Since there is no server code in my application, therefore downloading and zipping of the file is done in the browser itself.

Now The code is working fine to download small size file but it crashes the browser while handling larger files.

I am using Axios and JsZip utility in React js to build the application.
Can I use tar to avoid the usage of browser memory? Or is there a way to store the file stream in the local storage of the computer directly instead of saving in the browser's memory until the total file is downloaded.

Below is the code of my current implementation:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import JSZip from 'jszip'
import saveAs from 'file-saver'

const downloadObjectAsZip = (dispatch, urlArray) => {
  let zip = new JSZip()
  let count = 0
  const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
  source = CancelToken.source()
  urlArray.forEach((result) => {
  axios({
    url: result.url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob',
    cancelToken: source.token,
    onDownloadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
        // Update progress in progress bar
    }
    }).then((response) => {
        count++
    if (response.data.size) {
        const fileName = result.name
        zip.file(fileName, response.data, { binary: true })

    }

    }).catch((thrown) => {
            if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
        console.log('request cancel by user')
    } else {
        console.error('axios error', thrown.message);
    }
    })

    if(urlArray.length == count){
      zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function(content) {
        saveAs(content, `archive.zip`);
      })
    }
  })


}
```